partially decrypted bitlocker drive
here is my situation :
I've encrypted an external drive with a tool (M3 bitlocker on Mac) with a password. I wanted to remove the encryption but decryption was not part of the M3 bitlocker free trial, so I used Hasleo BitLocker Anywhere which is free.
The decryption was in progress until the software freezes, so I had to kill it.
Then I was unable to see my hard drive anymore.
Here is what I did then :

I succeeded to clone my hard drive with DMDE in my Windows computer
I did run chkdsk on this clone and it fixed some partitions
I mounted it as a virtual drive
I can access all my folders and files without password
Some files are accessibles and some are not (ex: some videos cannot be played)
I tried a lot of tools without any success :/

I've contacted the Hasleo BitLocker Anywhere support and they told me that decrypting the data is not possible anymore since the decryption process was aborted. It should have stored some *.bad file in /Applications/HasloeBitLockerAnywhere.app/Contents/MacOS but I've reinstalled the software so there no files there.
Do you have any ideas how could I decrypt all the files ?
Thanks in advance,

I would erase the drive and restore from a backup. Also, any app that stores data inside its own application bundle is pure garbage and shouldn’t be trusted with data.

If you haven't emptied your trash since deleting the original app, you can still go there. Find it in the trash, right click, and select "Show Package Contents"

sadly I've cleaned the trash :/
I've run another tool to lookup for deleted files on my entire Mac and it looks like there was no such file in Applications/HasloeBitLockerAnywhere.app/Contents/MacOS

This looks like you unfortunately have applied the equivalent of ransomware on yourself.
I would seek professional help and then decide how valuable that data on a corrupted drive is worth.
The commenter is correct, the likely path forward is restore the data from the most recent backup and evaluate other options that might meet your support and functional needs better than this product. Possibly knowing you can keep the .bad file next time a transformation fails might make all the difference though and you don’t need to change anything except perhaps backup interval or process.

I have no backup of the data :/ and I'm no able to see any .bad file at all, even with a recovery tool

That's understood and unfortunate @ersefuril Professionals do have tools and skills from interviewing many people that might be of use. Of course, if you don't value the data enough to monetarily compensate a pro, sadly it may be gone. No worries to leave the question up in case someone has a better idea in case you can let the drive sit unused until more information comes your way.

When you say professionals do you have any names/companies/contacts ?
